# openvpn route add windows problems

Tags: windows, linux, openvpn

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема:Есть openvpn сервер(linux, IP 111.111.111.111) и много клиентов(win xp) к нему подключающихся.На большинстве клиентских станций всё работает замечательно, но у некоторых не добавляются маршруты при старте службы openvpn, причём в логе клиента написано что добавление произошло успешно. При попытке перезапустить сервер руками периодически маршруты действительно добавляются.

Лог клиента:

```
Mon Nov 26 08:00:57 2012 us=62500 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 172.17.2.200 255.255.255.255,route 172.17.1.100 255.255.255.255,dhcp-option DNS 172.17.1.100,route 10.1.0.1,topology net30,ping 40,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.1.0.138 10.1.0.137'Mon Nov 26 08:00:57 2012 us=62500 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modifiedMon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 TEST ROUTES: 3/3 succeeded len=3 ret=1 a=0 u/d=upMon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 172.17.2.200 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137Mon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]Mon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 172.17.1.100     MASK 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137Mon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]Mon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 10.1.0.1 MASK     255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137Mon Nov 26 08:01:11 2012 us=500000 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]SYSTEM ROUTING TABLE0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.172 p=0 i=2 t=4 pr=3 a=34 h=0 m=10/-1/-1/-1/-110.1.0.1 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137 p=0 i=3 t=4 pr=3 a=0 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-110.1.0.136 255.255.255.252 10.1.0.138 p=0 i=3 t=3 pr=2 a=0 h=0 m=30/-1/-1/-1/-110.1.0.138 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=0 h=0 m=30/-1/-1/-1/-110.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.138 p=0 i=3 t=3 pr=2 a=0 h=0 m=30/-1/-1/-1/-1127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=41 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1172.17.1.100 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137 p=0 i=3 t=4 pr=3 a=0 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1172.17.2.200 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.137 p=0 i=3 t=4 pr=3 a=0 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.20 p=0 i=2 t=3 pr=2 a=34 h=0 m=10/-1/-1/-1/-1192.168.1.20 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=34 h=0 m=10/-1/-1/-1/-1192.168.1.255 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.20 p=0 i=2 t=3 pr=2 a=34 h=0 m=10/-1/-1/-1/-1224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 10.1.0.138 p=0 i=3 t=3 pr=2 a=0 h=0 m=30/-1/-1/-1/-1224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 192.168.1.20 p=0 i=2 t=3 pr=2 a=34 h=0 m=10/-1/-1/-1/-1255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.1.0.138 p=0 i=3 t=3 pr=2 a=41 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.20 p=0 i=2 t=3 pr=2 a=41 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1SYSTEM ADAPTER LIST
```

Конфиг сервера:

```
daemondev tunproto tcpport 1194#server ip & poolserver 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0push "route 172.17.2.200 255.255.255.255"push "route 172.17.1.100 255.255.255.255"tls-auth ta.key 0#certificatesca /etc/openvpn/easy_rsa/keys/ca.crtcert /etc/openvpn/easy_rsa/keys/MAIN_SERV.crtkey /etc/openvpn/easy_rsa/keys/MAIN_SERV.keydh /etc/openvpn/easy_rsa/keys/dh1024.pem#revoke listcrl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl/crl.pem#general settingscomp-lzokeepalive 40 120#need to downgrade privilegiesuser nobodygroup nobodypersist-keypersist-tun
```

Конфиг клиента

```
dev tunproto tcpport 1194client# vpn serverremote 111.111.111.111ns-cert-type server#certificatesca ./ca.crtcert ./win_test.crtkey ./win_test.keytls-auth ta.key 1#general settingscomp-lzo#check is server aliveping 40register-dnsreneg-sec 0#log settingsstatus vpn_status.loglog client.logverb 10
```

На клиенте после установления соединения route print не содержит маршрутов к 172.17.2.200 и 172.17.1.100

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема.

P.S:Все внешние IP адреса вымышлены а совпадения с ними случайны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиг клиентов надо добавить следующее

```
route-method exe route-delay 2
```

Это справедливо и для 7-ки

Comment: @sharptop, думаете в этом проблема?Подозреваю что раз таблица маршрутизации в логе выпечатывается правильно, а потом на клиенте пропадает то ктото/чтото периодически затирает записи в таблице.Может ли какая-нибудь политика AD/Netware заниматься подобными гадостями?

Comment: Рекомендую почитать тему на ixbt по этому поводу http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=14:40906 - там довольно таки подробно изложено, из-за чего может возникать такая ошибка. Я лично сталкивался с такой же проблемой и это было рабочим решением.

Answer (score 1):

Был подобный случай, помог только сброс параметров `tcp\ip`.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357